# Java 8 streams and simple types

Tags: java, java-stream

Can anyone explain to me why the following does not work:

```
long la[] = new long[] {1,2,3};
Arrays.stream(la).map(Long::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

When this does:

```
String la[] = new String[] {"1","2","3"};
Arrays.stream(la).map(Long::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The former gives a compilation error while the latter does not. The compilation error is so cryptic (Eclipse) that I cannot make sense of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.stream(la)` executes the method [`public static LongStream stream(long[] array)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-long:A-) which produces a `LongStream`. `LongStream`'s [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#map-java.util.function.LongUnaryOperator-) method returns a `LongStream` (i.e. each `long` element of the source `LongStream` is mapped to a `long` element in the target `LongStream`). `LongStream` doesn't have a `collect` method that accepts a single argument, which is why `collect(Collectors.toSet())` doesn't pass compilation.

It should work if you use `mapToObj` :

```
Set<Long> set = Arrays.stream(la).mapToObj(Long::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Your second snippet works since here `Arrays.stream` produces a `Stream` of a reference type (`Stream<String>`) whose [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method produces another `Stream` of a reference type (`Stream<Long>` in your case). Here, `Stream` has a `collect` method that accepts a single argument - `collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector)` - so `collect(Collectors.toSet())` works.

Comment: This will solve the problem but it doesn't explain why the first snippet doesn't compile though.

Comment: Shorter: `Arrays.stream(la).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: `LongUnaryOperator o = Long::valueOf` compiles fine. This is not the problem.

Comment: It is not be a problem to provide a function `long -> Long` when it expects a function `long -> long`, due to autoboxing (you will just do unecessary conversions). The problem is with the `collect` call.

Comment: I ended up using .boxed() which is shorter and more explict than mapToObj(). But thanks a lot for the explanation, it made a lot of sense.

Comment: @user1283068 Beware that the explanation is incorrect though. See my comment above and Alexis C.'s.

Comment: But Alexis C just states that the problem is with the collect call, not what the problem is or in what way this invalidates the explanation provided by Eran.

Comment: @user1283068 Alexis was right. I didn't have time to test this code last week (was mostly away from my computer), so only now I had time to verify it. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The code only looks the same. The method `Arrays.stream` that is being called is actually different in both cases:

- First snippet: [`stream(long[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-long:A-) which returns a [`LongStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html). This is a primitive specialization of a stream for `long` elements.
- Second snippet: [`stream(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) (where `T = String` here) wich returns a [`Stream<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

On a `Stream<String>`, you can call [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and return a `Stream<R>` based on the return type of the mapper. But on a `LongStream`, [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#map-java.util.function.LongUnaryOperator-) will always return a `LongStream`, that is the primitive specialization. What happens is that `Long::valueOf` will turn your `long` element into a `Long` object and then it will be automatically unboxed into a `long`; effectively, the call is doing nothing except a box / unbox.

Then the problem appears on the `collect` call.

- [`LongStream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjLongConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) expects 3 arguments
- [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) has a 3 argument method but also a 1 argument method, which is the one you call with `.collect(Collectors.toSet());`.

So you can't call `.collect(Collectors.toSet());` on a `LongStream`. This won't compile: it expects 3 arguments.

What you can do is call [`mapToObj`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.LongFunction-) instead of `map` on the `LongStream`: this method declares to return a `Stream<R>` (instead of a `LongStream`) from the return type of the mapper. In this case, the mapper is `Long::valueOf` that returns a `Long` object so it will return a `Stream<Long>`.

To recap:

```
  long la[] = new long[] {1,2,3};
  Arrays.stream(la).map(Long::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toSet());
//^--LongStream----^^---LongStream----^^     error

  String la[] = new String[] {"1","2","3"};
  Arrays.stream(la).map(Long::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toSet());
//^-Stream<String>-^^--Stream<Long>--^^---- successful call -----^

  long la[] = new long[] {1,2,3};
  Arrays.stream(la).mapToObj(Long::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toSet());
//^--LongStream----^^-----Stream<Long>-----^^---- successful call -----^
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

To answer why the first one doesn't compile, this creates a `LongStream`:

```
Arrays.stream(la)
```

This takes each `long`, creates a `Long` wrapper, then unboxes it back to `long`.  Stream is still a `LongStream`:

```
.map(Long::valueOf)
```

This passes a single parameter to `LongStream.collect`, which fails because `LongStream.collect` required 3 parameters:

```
.collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

You need to change the `map` to `mapToObj` if you want to change the `LongStream` into a `Stream<Long>` (or call `LongStream.boxed()`)